# (ASP.NET MVC5) How to change default time out of 5 mins?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, session-cookies, identityserver3, openid-connect

I have a web app developed with ASPNET MVC5 in which authentication is done by IdentityServer3 using OpenIdConnect (IdP is configured to use Google+).

The issue is that, my session is always timed out after 5 mins even I set cookie & session to 60 mins.

Below is the code:

This code is on Startup of the **client**

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            CookieName = "RefManWeb",
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
        });
```

Also I have sessionState set in Web.config

```
<sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
```

Can you guy point out what is wrong here ? Any advice is much appriciated !

**Update:** all cookies have exprires = "At end of session".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`SlidingExpiration` only works with option `UseTokenLifetime = false` in your OpenID middleware.

for e.g.

```
 app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication( new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                Authority = options.AuthorityUrl.ToString(),
                ClientId = options.Client.Id.ToString(),
                RedirectUri = options.Client.Url.ToString(),
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = options.Client.Url.ToString(),
                ResponseType = "id_token",
                UseTokenLifetime = false,
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = options.CookieName,
                Notifications = new CustomNotificationProvider()
            });
```

Comment: with your help now it won't be timed out after 5 min. BUT the session seems not being timed out anymore. I changed datetime to next day/month, it is still signed in even expiration still is 60 mins.

Comment: even 1 hour idle?

Comment: I did not idle 1h but I changed local time to 2h, or 1 day (should equal to idle)